# Correct url path in leaflet markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I want to personalize my leaflet markers, for this reason I'm reading this [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/).

My problem is in `iconUrl` because it can't find the path of the images. Here in the documentation, they just write,

```
iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png'
```

But if I just write this, the path is wrong.

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/dataMap/leaf-green.png 404 (Not Found)

Then my idea was, I'm in the `js` folder, I have to write the path from here to the marker.

```
iconUrl: '../img/markers/leaf-green.png',
```

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/markers/leaf-green.png 404 (Not Found)

Here is my structure

[image]

It doesn't work too. Then, how I have to write the path?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JS executes from the context of the URL of the current page, not the location of the JS file in the folder structure. Therefore it looks like the path needs to include your `static` folder (and any above it that are not pictured).

However, the best practice is to make all URLs relative to the site root by prefixing them with `/`. This avoids any issues when running JS from nested pages, deep within a real or virtual path. Try this:

```
iconUrl: '/static/img/markers/leaf-green.png'
```